# How can I find the source code of any google doodle?

Tags: html, embed

I am trying to find embed in HTML for the Halloween 2018 (https://www.google.com/doodles/halloween-2018) google doodle into a site.
I have tried view-source, but I only get a gif for the cover for the doodle.
Is there any other way I can get the HTML source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view-source:https://www.google.com/doodles/halloween-2018
That?
Did you try it after you clicked the doodle? I just opened it up, then did ctrl-U
Also, you could just put view-source: in front of any url and open it up without doing it from the site